# Probability Density and Distribution of a Sphere

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I am given that the density function for the radii of a sphere is constant over 0 < r<5 and zero elsewhere and am asked for calculate the density function f(r) and the cumulative distribution function F(r).

I understand that the integrand of p(x) over 0 to 5 equals 1 and that any x in between is thereby a percentage or the probability density that x occurs at an interval between a and b.

I also understand that the Cumulative Distribution Function is P(x), the antiderivative of p(x). Defined by p(x)dx over 0 to 5 equals P(b)-P(a).

I guess I'm just not sure how to calculate the pdf in this instance.

Comment: Why do you think that spheres are related to this concept? Also, why does your sphere have radius 0; that seems a bit strange, doesn't it?

Comment: My bad. Needed to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The fact that the density is constant means that $f(x)=\delta$ whenever $x$ is in the sphere. The fact that density functions must be normalized means precisely that $1=\int_\text{sphere} \delta~ dV$.

Can you take it from here?